# Java ProcessBuilder in ubuntu with bmdcapture

Tags: java, ubuntu, avconv

I am working on live streaming from blackmagic decklink card. So for that I need to execute a command.

```
String[] command={"./bmdcapture", "-m", "10", "-C", "0", "-V", "3", "-A", "2", "-F", "nut", "-f", "pipe:1", "|", "./avconv", "-i", "-", "-strict", "experimental", "-c:v", "libx264", "test.mp4"};
File f = new File("/home/NetBeansProjects/tools/card");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.directory(f);
pb.directory(f);
Process process = pb.start();
```

its works perfectly in terminal, But when i invoke via process-builder using java not working.

Comment: And how doesn't it work? You don't tell anything about the problem. "doesn't work" doesn't help.

Comment: result is bmdcapture: invalid option -- 'i'. the pipe symbol not working

Comment: Aah, I didn't see the pipe. No wonder it's not working...

Comment: Yoi either need to chain the pipe yourself or you pass all of the command to `/bin/sh -c`

Comment: thanks I changed like this String[] commands={"/bin/sh", "-c","./bmdcapture -m 10 -C 0 -V 3 -A 2 -F nut -f pipe:1 | ./avconv -y -i - -strict experimental -c:v libx264 test.mp4"}; it's works

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is really a classic but I guess this still needs to be hammered into heads from time to time, and preferrably using a sledgehammer, and here the sledgehammer will be some bold font...

**A `ProcessBuilder` does not run its processes via a command interpreter; as such, any command interpreter metacharacters, such as the `*` and the `|`, will be left untouched.**

In your example, what you are basically trying to do is to pipe one command into another using a `ProcessBuilder`. But while this:

```
cmd1 | cmd2
```

will work in a Unix shell, this:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd1", "|", "cmd2")
```

will not. A `ProcessBuilder` has no idea what a pipe sign is and will just pass it as an argument to the command being issued (here, `cmd1`). This is the same behaviour you have with, for instance, `execve()` in the standard C library.

If you really want to pipe the output of a command into another you'll have to use *two* `ProcessBuilder`s (one for each command) and redirect the output of the first command to the input of the second.